# read gmail pop3 using c++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I want to read my Gmail inbox emails using c++ builder so I use this code I got it from videos on youtube, but before i read i tried to connect first using this code in the button.

```
MyPoP3
POP3->Host = "pop.gmail.com";
POP3->Port = 995;
POP3->Username = "@gmail.com";
POP3->Password = "my pass";

POP3->Connect();
Memo1->Text = "Number = " + IntToStr(MyPoP3->CheckMessages()) + "\n";
MyPoP3->Disconnect();
```

and i got this error message after a short delay.

```
error connection closed gracefully
```

this my first time iam use c++ builder I just learn it so please any help with that error because I can't find any good resource for it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means the server is closing its end of the TCP connection.

POP3 port 995 uses SSL encryption, so in order to communicate with Gmail on port 995, you must:

- assign an `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component to the `TIdPOP3.IOHandler` property, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` (and deploy the 2 OpenSSL DLLs with your app).
- set the `TIdPOP3.UseTLS` property to `utUseImplicitTLS`.
- if you have 2-factor authentication enabled in your Gmail account, create an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for your app to use instead of your real Gmail password (as Indy does not yet implement [support for OAuth authentication](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/192) for POP3 and other protocols).

Comment: Thank you it works fine without the error but i have one last question when i check the message in my inbox i got 0 but i have alot of emails i use code in question update

Comment: If `CheckMessages() returns 0, there are simply no messages available to download via POP3. Did you enable POP3 access in your Gmail settings?  You might consider accessing your Gmail using IMAP instead.

Comment: yea bro thank you very much for this help I change it before I asked the question but I not saved :) my bad, anyway thank you it worked fine