# Error Connection Closed Gracefully using Indy 10 and TidPOP3 in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm only using TidPOP3 component from Indy 10 and my code is below:

```
type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
  Button1: TButton;
  Pop3: TIdPOP3;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Mensaje : TIdMessage;
  RchTMessage: TRichEdit;

procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Pop3 := TIdPOP3.Create;
    Pop3.Host := 'pop.gmail.com';
    Pop3.Port := 995;
    Pop3.Username := '**********@gmail.com';
    Pop3.Password := '**********';

try
  if not Pop3.Connected then
  begin
    Pop3.Connect;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
except on E: Exception do RchTMessage.Lines.Add(E.Message);
end;

end;

end.
```

When I press the button I got the Error "Connection Closed Gracefully". I've already configured the gmail account i'm using to be ready to accept Pop3 connections and to accept non-secure connections from other apps. Also, I configured TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component in the form.

Thanks and Happy New Year for everyone.

Comment: Related : [read gmail pop3 using c++ builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51736890/)

Answer (score 0):

Your button `OnClick` handler is creating a new `TIdPOP3` object instead of using the one that you dropped on your Form. You are not configuring that object to interact with Gmail using SSL/TLS, as you are not attaching the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to it, or setting its `UseTLS` property (to `utUseImplicitTLS`) .